# My button does nothing when i click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, loading

I have a button

```
<script>
function changeMap() {
 container.setMap(oMap); 
}   
</script>
<button onClick="changeMap"> Click here </button>
```

The content of container is correct. it has a control.
The set Map property exists from what i see in the console.

When the page loads all is correct. but when i click the button the property doesn't set OR the content of the page doesn't change.

Do i need to load some other way? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's `onclick`, not `onClick`. And you need to call the function `changeMap()`.

Comment: `onclick="changeMap()"` - you have to call it in an onclick html attribute

Comment: @Kinduser HTML is *not* case sensitive.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak To add, while HTML itself is case-insensitive, accessing the attribute in JavaScript *is*: `foo.onclick`, not `foo.onClick`.

Comment: @AndrewLi The case described is not "accessing the attribute in JavaScript", it's plain HTML.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I understand that, was just making a note for Kind user, to clear the confusion.

Comment: even after making all of the above changes. When i use the console to getMap() after i have done setMap() it shows the correct output. getMap() = oMap. however, the page doesnt reflect this. it remains the same. how can i update the page with the correct output too?

Comment: does my answer help at all? if not could you please comment as to what still isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<button  onclick="changeMap()">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The attribute is called `onclick` not `onClick`,</strike> Apparently html attributes are fully case insensitive, so both will work.

However you also need parentheses after the name of the function.

```
<button onclick="changeMap(event)">Click Here</button>
```

here the `event` is a browser global that allows us to pass an event to the handler. In your case, you aren't using the event, so it is not necessary.

Please also note that if you add the event in javascript, you will not use the parentheses.

I have included a demo of three different ways to add a click handler to a button below.

```js
function log(message){
   var line = document.createElement('div');
   var text = document.createTextNode(message);
   line.appendChild(text);
   messages.appendChild(line);
}

function handleClick(e){
   log("Click from " + e.target.id);
}

// add an event listener to b2
b3.onclick = handleClick;

// add an event listener to b3
b4.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick(event);" id="b1" >Button 1</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event);" id="b2" >Button 2</button>
<button id="b3">Button 3</button>
<button id="b4">Button 4</button>

<div id="messages">
</div>
```

Comment: HTML attributes aren't case sensitive, but of course you're right about the parentheses.

Comment: interesting, I hadn't realized that. I guess the parentheses were the problem then. Thanks for sharing.